# Updated from corda 3.1 -> 3.2, now can't start node

Tags: corda

During node startup I get this exception:

```
[ERROR] 2018-11-01T13:11:38,159Z [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup {} java.lang.NullPointerException: couldn't find factory for type=3
```

What does "couldn't find factory for type=3" mean?

I'm not sure what else to provide to make debugging easier, but let me know if there's anything missing!

Answer (score 0):

This is known to have been fixed by deleting the node's `artemis` folder before restarting it.